# How do I fill an entire column in mysql with hash generated from username in that row

Tags: php, mysql, hash

The query I have so far is :

```
create table users_csv_import
(
  username varchar(255),
  reg_link varchar(255)
);

insert into users_csv_import (username, reg_link)
values ('kns2184', 'NULL');
insert into users_csv_import (username, reg_link)
values ('kns2185', 'NULL');
insert into users_csv_import (username, reg_link)
values ('kns2186', 'NULL');
insert into users_csv_import (username, reg_link)
values ('kns2187', 'NULL');
insert into users_csv_import (username, reg_link)
values ('kns2188', 'NULL');

update users_csv_import
set reg_link = md5(username in row should go here?)
where reg_link='NULL';
```

So what I would like to do is for every row generate md5 hash from username in that row. I do not want to use a php loop, I would like to do this through mysql because I assume it will be much faster then something like an array of generated hashes via php.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da389/1

Comment: If you are using this md5 hash as a password, I would strongly advise against it. md5 is considered too fast to be a good hashing algorithm.

Comment: I am not using md5 for password hashing. This is just used to generate a custom link for user and we probably won't end up using md5 I just need help with dynamic query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you say in your post (almost):

```
update users_csv_import
set reg_link = md5(username)
where reg_link IS NULL;
```

Comment: Haha, thanks sometimes it better to trust your gut feeling :)